# What plugin presents these extra columns in wp-admin -> plugins

Tags: plugins, admin

One of my customer's websites shows very usefull extra information on the plugin page. But for the life of me I can't find any plugin in the list that does this (there are at least 35+ plugins used and all of them are content related).

Anybody seen this before?

[image]